# Vagrant + Puppets modules

Tags: nginx, varnish, puppet, vagrant, zend-server

is anywhere good resource for puppet modules? I need something for nginx, varnish and zend-server ce, i'm sure that would be somewhere just I cannot find it.

Thanks in advance,
Jaro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the puppet labs repository of modules!

http://forge.puppetlabs.com/

Hope that's what you're looking for!

Cheers,

Jake

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot of resources. Jaro :)